# How to create DataGrid with items based on datatype

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

I want to display different members of my Itemssource on a datagrid as Tiles where I can edit them ,The editing options on Tiles should be based on data types like if its an enum then a combobox should be available  with current item highlighted,If its a string than normal editing should be done.

My Tile with enum values should look something like this,where None is the current value out of Enum(Single,None,All).Can Anybody provide some sample code to style datagrid cell template for this.Iam using MVVM

[image: My item with enum values should look like this]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a combobox:

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="FirstVariable" 
                      SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=RootControl, Path=Request.Analysis.Variables[0]}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding VariableTypeValues, ElementName=RootControl}"
                      />
```

and

```
public IEnumerable<VariableType> VariableTypeValues
    {
        get
        {
            return Enum.GetValues(typeof(VariableType)).Cast<VariableType>();
        }
    }
```

to get the enum values in. Request.Analysis.Variables[0] is of type VariableType.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataGridTemplateColumn and set CellEditingTemplateSelector to a custom DataTemplateSelector which will provide specific editing template depending on the cell value data type. 
[Just found one that matches yours request](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/418250/WPF-Based-Dynamic-DataTemplateSelector).